# How to close modal after all requests by RTK Query are done?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a modal form which works this way:

- On submit click in modal form mutation fires `POST` request.
- If response is successfull then modal closes.
- `GET` request sent by RTK Query for data.
- Data received and rendered.
  **Problem:** modal closes and user doesn't see a created post for couple of seconds because `GET` request is not finished yet.

What I want to do

- On submit click in modal form mutation fires `POST` request.
- If response is successfull then modal do not close waiting for `GET` request response.
- When data received then modal closes and there's an actual UI
  **Result:** user clicks submit then after all requests are finished modal closes and user see a newly created post immidiately.

**Api**

```
getAllFaces: builder.query<Face[], void>({
  query: () => 'face/',
  transformResponse: (response: Face[]) => {
    response.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.created_date).valueOf() - new Date(a.created_date).valueOf());
    return handleObjDate(response);
  },
  providesTags: (result) =>
    result
      ? [...result.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Faces' as const, id })), { type: 'Faces', id: 'LIST' }]
      : [{ type: 'Faces', id: 'LIST' }],
}),
createFace: builder.mutation<Face, Pick<Face, 'name'>>({
  query: (body) => ({
    url: 'face/',
    method: 'POST',
    body,
  }),
  invalidatesTags: [{ type: 'Faces', id: 'LIST' }],
}),
```

Submit function

```
  const onSubmit = async (data: FormValues) => {
    await createFace(data);
    onClose();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest an alternative:
Let the modal close and have some kind of non-blocking loading indicator in your list.
The user sees "something is happening/loading", but can already interact with other list elements if they are interested in doing that, without being forced to wait those additional 2 seconds.

You can use `isFetching` of your `useGetAllFacesQuery` result for that.